# Why does a keydown event get broadcasted to a newly rendered component?

Tags: vue.js

I want to conditionally render a component based on the user's keypress.
Once the new component is rendered, an input field should get focused.

For some reason, Vue broadcasts the keypress I use to render the component to the new component! The result is that the key I pressed to render the component gets displayed in the input field!

How is that even possible? The keypress triggers the mounting of the new component and the focusing of the input only happens after it is mounted.

**Minimum working example:**

```
// App.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <p>App</p>
    <Hello v-if="view == 'hello'" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from "./components/Hello.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Hello
  },
  data() {
    return {
      view: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeView() {
      this.view = "hello";
    }
  },
  created() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.changeView);
  }
};
</script>
```

```
// Hello.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <input ref="input" type="text" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.input.focus();
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a minimum working example, this is an image.
Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @UtsavPatel You can't see the code above the image?

Comment: I can see the code, but I cannot reproduce the issue you are facing just by seeing the code and image you shared.
Perhaps you can read the link I shared above.

Comment: @UtsavPatel I don't know if you're being serious. Yes, I know the content of the link. What part of the minimum example is not understandable to you? This is the whole app, there is nothing more. You can copy paste this into your @vue-cli project folder and execute `npm run serve`

Answer (score 1):

This is because the events are flowing like this:
`keydown` renders the new component -> `focus` moved to new component -> `keyup` fires in new component (where is focus now) and character stays there.

Change the trigger to `keyup` and it should work.

Comment: `keyup` solves the problem but makes the app slightly less responsive to key presses. Why does `keyup` fire once the new component gets rendered? The letter is already in the input field before I release the key.

Comment: Because `keyup` fires after `keydown` and all events that happens after keydown.

Comment: As far as I know `keyup` only fires once you release the key. However, the letter already appears in the `input field` before I release the key. That's the part which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I am not sure about exact behaviour of keydown on document and then focusing the input. Try to reproduce this with multiple inputs instead